# How do you associate a bug identified after customer acceptance with the relevant epic?

Tags: jira, bugs, epics

In my understanding there are two kinds of bugs:

1. Bugs that are identified before an acceptance by the client
2. Bugs that are identified afterwards

In JIRA I think it is necessary to associate bug type 1 with an Epic as they are a condition for completing the Epic.

But how do you treat bug type 2? As far as I understand it the epic should already be closed (see [my related question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/22783/reopen-an-epic-after-a-feature-request)). Do you associate no epic at all? Do you use a "bugs" epic? Anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of traceability can become difficult and problematic as one backlog item or even epics modify the behavior of a previous one, but if you do want to link them, you can still use JIRA's "relates to" functionality even if an issue is closed.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracorecloud/linking-issues-779296002.html